# Laravel 5.4 ‘cross-env’ Is Not Recognized as an Internal or External Command

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I'm trying to run `npm run dev` for Laravel Mix and I get this error:

```
> @ dev D:\projects\ptcs
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-modules --
config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-
modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
```

I updated node.js to 6.11.0 and npm to 5.2.0, but it didn't help. I'm running Homestead on Windows 7.

Comment: I think it depends if you run then install from Homestead or Windows 7, because it install OS specific libraries.

Comment: For me re-installing latest node.js (8.9) fixed this issue.

Comment: after Yevgeniy Afanasyev advice if you encounter that error: > The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. you should run that command: $ npm install webpack-cli -D

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You need to make cross-env working globally instead of having it in the project.

1) remove **`node_modules`** folder

2) run

> npm install --global cross-env

3) remove `"cross-env": "^5.0.1",` from `package.json` file `devDependencies` section. Actually, you can skip this step and keep package.json intact. If you prefer.

4) run

> npm install --no-bin-links

5) run

> `npm run dev`

and see it working

*P.S Tested on Windows 10 with Laravel-5.4*

*P.P.S Windows 10 with Laravel-5.6 does not have this problem, thus **updating** is an alternative solution.*

Comment: It is tested and confirmed working on Ubuntu set as a Virtual Box on Vagrant wint Laravel 5.4 (Homestead). With win10 as a base operation system.

Comment: Because I didn't know for what the command `npm install --no-bin-links` is used for (even researching, I didn't understand) I avoided to use it, and worked. Why is that necessary?

Comment: "binary links" is similar to "shortcut" for windows, but binary links work on Linux. As you have your files on windows host you would not need bin-links in Linux format seating there.

Comment: great! it works like a charm. I used `npm install` instead `npm install --no-bin-links` what is the difference ? thanks in advanced.

Comment: `--no-bin-links` is for windows, it does not create binary links.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem this noon. But I only did step 2 and 3, and deleted the corresponding cross-env package folder in the node_modules folder and package-lock.json. It worked.

Comment: deleting the `node_modules` and running `npm install` again works for me

Comment: tested with laravel 8 also and it run

Comment: We must favor having a repository/source-code self-sufficient. Meaning that by just downloading and running it, the application works. I suggest adding "cross-env" to the "devDependencies" section so any new onboarding developer would get the repository and run the code without having to go through, sometimes extensive, pre-environment configuration.

Answer (score 40):

**First run:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
```

**Then run the command**

```
npm install cross-env

npm install
```

and then you can also run

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: without removing any files and without clearing cache i followed rest of the command ...its worked perfectly ..Thanks flick

Comment: Unfortunately these steps didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 28):

Following these steps solved my problem.

1. Delete `node_modules` directory
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file
3. Start command prompt as Administrator **<- important**
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 16):

You are getting the error because you might not have run the command `npm install` first.

i.e.
First, run `npm install` and then `npm run dev`

Answer (score 9):

There is the same problem in Linux OS. The issue is related on Windows OS, but Homestead is a Ubuntu VM, and the solution posted works strongly good in others SO. I applied the commands sugested by flik, and the problems was solved. I only used the following commands

**I only used the following commands**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear --force
```

**After**

```
npm install cross-env
npm install 
npm run watch
```

It's working fine on linux Fedora 25.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this issue comment](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478#issuecomment-284191242), editing `cross-env` path will fix the problem. Change `cross-env` to `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js` in `package.json` like this:

```
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

Comment: For those who tried this and it did not work, as a next step of this instruction 1) delete node_modules folder from the product and 2) reinstall it with "npm install --no-bin-links". 3) try "npm run dev" and see it working. BESIDES this approach works on WIN10, but not working on Ubuntu-Laravel-5.4-Homestead. I posted my own answer here that works for windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

For me simply run:

```
npm install cross-env
```

was enough

Answer (score 5):

Your error states that cross-env is not installed.

```
'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

You just need to run

```
npm install cross-env
```

Answer (score 5):

Just `npm install --save-dev cross-env` in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for **Laravel 7.x** (and should probably work for any other version as well given the nature of the issue).

```
npm uninstall --save-dev cross-env
npm install -g cross-env
```

Just moving **cross-env** from being a local devDependency to a globally available package.

Comment: +1 because this worked, and I couldn't find any other answer that worked. But this feels like a hack that doesn't address the root cause of why the project-specific installation of `cross-env` wasn't working. And in my case, I'm reasonably sure that it *used to work*, so I'm confused about why it stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

Before try running `npm run dev`
please run `npm install --no-bin-links` in the project directory, this will install all required packages.
Also check this link for compiling instruction.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Also double check in your `conf` file, wherever you find something like this

`(something)/cross-env/bin/(something)`

change it to

`(something)/cross-env/dist/bin/(something)`

If you are using homestead, in `package.json` paste this

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

Also check this link 
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478

Comment: Yes, it installed npm successfully.

Comment: Please run `npm install cros-env`

Comment: after `npm install cross-env` I get a different error when trying to `npm run dev`: $ npm run dev

> @ dev D:\projects\ptcs
> npm run development

npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"

> @ development D:\projects\ptcs
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

The system cannot find the path specified.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: Also run this please `npm install --no-bin-links`

Comment: Adding `--no-bin-links` to `npm install` didn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (on Windows 10):

1. Add the following lines into your scripts in the package.json file:

   ```
   "dev": "npm run development",
   "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
   "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
   "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
   "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
   "prod": "npm run production",
   "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
   ```
2. Make your devDependencies looks something like this:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
       "axios": "^0.18",
       "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
       "popper.js": "^1.12",
       "cross-env": "^5.1",
       "jquery": "^3.2",
       "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
       "lodash": "^4.17.4",
       "vue": "^2.5.7"
   }
   ```
3. Remove `node_modules` folder
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 2):

I think this log entry **Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?** has gave me the solution.

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply try running `npm install` / `yarn` etc first before running `npm start` / `yarn` start as @only4 mentioned, if you see this problem, as it means your `.env` is not in sync with your `package.json`, i.e. you installed a package but not quite configured it or other way around

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `node_modules` folder

Then you should run the commands:

```
npm install --no-bin-links

npm run dev
```

It's worked on my Laravel 5.5 and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `npm run dev` in powershell. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I real all the solution but there is not a standard solution...

JUST REMOVE NODEJS AND INSTALL THE LATEST VERSION OF NODEJS

instead of many bad shortcut solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by following these steps:

1. Remove the file `package-lock.json`
2. Run the command: `npm install --force`
3. Try again to execute `npm start`