# How can I compile assets using Laravel Mix?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I use laravel 5.4

I follow here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

If I run this : `npm install --no-bin-links`, the result like this :

> npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
>   npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\chelsea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "install" "--no-bin-links" npm ERR! node v6.9.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
>
> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded npm ERR! npm ERR! If you
>   need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\npm-debug.log

There exist error

How can I solve the error?

I use windows 7

I want to fix the error, because I want to compile assets (`npm run watch`)

Update :

After that I try run `npm run dev`, the result like this :

> > @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop
> >     npm run development
> >
> > @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop
> >     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\chelsea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "run" "development" npm ERR! node v6.9.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm
>   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env
>   NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress
>   --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script
>   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>   --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails
>   on your system: npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development
>   node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules
>   --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm
>   ERR!     npm bugs npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
>   their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\chelsea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "run" "dev" npm ERR! node v6.9.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development` npm ERR! Exit status
>   1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the 
>   package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that
>   this fails on your system: npm ERR!     npm run development npm ERR!
>   You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
>   their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\npm-debug.log

I try fix it with answer from @Yevgeniy Afanasyev

This : [Laravel 5.4 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034581/laravel-5-4-cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

But it's the same

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute this command one more time.

Comment: The result like this : `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`
`

Comment: Well I see, you updated your answer. Now, I think you should try to install modules which npm needs. For example, you have message about 'cross env'', so try to install it `npm install --save-dev cross-env`

Comment: There is still error. Like this : 
`npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\chelsea\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\npm-debug.log`
`

Comment: Seems to be strange. This error tells about the problems with the memory of your device. Does it appear when you try to install cross-dev?

Comment: Yes. You try to updating your answer with a more detailed answer

Comment: If you run into Node Sass issues it's known to run correctly with Node 6.x (`node-gyp node-sass`)