# 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install, laravel-mix

Guys can you please help me on this I have trouble run npm run dev for my Laravel Mix. I followed links below but still error exist. Do i have a problem on my OS? I tried to remove **node_modules**, run *npm install --global cross-env*. and run NPM install again.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478

[Laravel 5.4 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034581/laravel-5-4-cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Here are my versions:

- Laravel mix version: ^2.0
- Node Version (node -v): 8.9.0
- NPM Version (npm -v): 5.6.0
- OS: Windows7
- XAMPP

```
> @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\codetinerant
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Garciano\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-17T10_08_34_901Z-debug.log
```

Comment: update your Nodejs and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**First, run:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
```

**Then run the command**

```
npm install cross-env

npm install
```

**and then you can also run**

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: The ease and smooth way to handle that. Thank you!

Comment: Use powershell for install `npm-install`

Comment: I tried 2 times but that above solution not works for me. then I found another solution at github issues ... simply run `npm install --save-dev cross-env` command then my problem has solved... https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app/issues/97

Answer (score 17):

Did you try specifying the path to `cross-env` as suggested by [dwoodward](https://github.com/dwoodard) on the [Github issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478) you linked. This goes in your `package.json` file:

```
"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

This may have changed in more recent versions of Laravel but the gist is that you should change `cross-env` to `node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js`.

Comment: Thank you, i added node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js in my package.json file and it now worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try install cross-env globally.

run

```
sudo npm i -g cross-env
```

Answer (score 1):

Try install cross-env:

```
npm install cross-env
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Add the npm bin directory to your system path
e.g `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin`

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by uninstalling node and then running the following command.

```
npm install -d
```