# Why I can not run Npm run dev?

Tags: npm, npm-install, laravel-mix

Guys can you please help me on this I have trouble run **npm run dev** for my Laravel Mix. I followed links below but still error exist. Do i have a problem on my OS? I tried to remove node_modules, run npm install --global cross-env. and run NPM install again.

['cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840341/cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478

The error I always get when I ran `npm run dev` :

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/baloghdominik/.npm/_logs/2020-02-26T17_05_54_290Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/baloghdominik/.npm/_logs/2020-02-26T17_05_54_315Z-debug.log
```

Comment: show us your package.json content. node version npm version could be usefull too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First run

```
npm install cross-env

npm install
```

**Then run**

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: That will not work as this is cache problem .

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you thank you. @Dominik Balogh

Comment: works fine, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Simple steps :

1. npm cache clear --force
2. delete node_modules and package-lock.json
3. npm install
4. npm run dev

Answer (score 5):

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Basically delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file , clear cache and do an npm install. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had old version of node.js
so I just installed version I need:

`sudo npm install n -g`

`sudo n stable`

Or can try use latest:

`sudo n latest`

Answer (score 0):

If u using `nvm`, u need use version for project. Commands helped for me:

1. Use default version node: `nvm use system`
2. Remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules` and `rm -f package-lock.json`
3. Clear cache `npm cache clear --force`
4. Finished command `npm i`