# Install bulma in laravel

Tags: laravel, bulma

I want ton install Bulma via NPM im using NPM install bulma but what should i do after that? 
I added bulma snippet in app.scss

```
// Bulma
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";
```

And when I use NPM run dev I get this error with this log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\laragon\www\vue\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;;D:\laragon\bin\laragon\utils;D:\laragon\bin\mysql\mariadb-10.3.10-winx64\bin;D:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64;D:\laragon\bin\composer;D:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\bin;D:\laragon\bin\redis\redis-x64-3.2.100;D:\laragon\bin\nginx\nginx-1.14.0;D:\laragon\bin\notepad++;D:\laragon\bin\telnet;D:\laragon\bin\ngrok;D:\laragon\bin;D:\laragon\usr\bin;D:\laragon\bin\putty;D:\laragon\bin\cmder\bin;D:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;D:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;D:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;;D:\laragon\bin\cmder\;
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: D:\laragon\www\vue
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd D:\laragon\www\vue
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v8.7.0
19 verbose npm  v5.4.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do `@import "~bulma";` if you're using scss.

Comment: @swonder when I use the command npm run dev to finish the install I get an error

Comment: found a solution thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034581/laravel-5-4-cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 0):

You can import bulma in SCSS using
`@import "bulma/bulma.sass";`