# bug in laravel 6 mix, and returns page isn’t working

Tags: php, webpack, laravel-6, laravel-mix

I got an issue here and that is when I run

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
npm run watch-poll
```

in the terminal it's open the browser in

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

because had written in the `webpack.mix.js` file this code:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sourceMaps()
.browserSync('http://localhost:8000/');
```

but when it opens the browser it's keeps loading and at the end it giving me that blank screen with ***This page isn’t working*** in it, like the attached image here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out a post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852128/npm-run-watch-is-not-working-in-laravel-6-0) and it's helped me a lot by reinstalling the cross-env by typing `sudo npm install cross-env`