# Why 'npm run watch' gives error in laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel

I am following this tutorial http://w3programmers.com/bangla/build-an-e-commerce-project-with-laravel-in-bangla-part-6/ . In this tutorial when executing 'npm run watch' in command prompt, an app.js file creates in public/backend/js. But when I execute 'npm run watch' no such file created. After executing 'npm run watch' command I found this in command prompt

```
> @ watch E:\Laravel\ecommerce-application
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development E:\Laravel\ecommerce-application
> node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Laravel\ecommerce-application\node_modules\cross-env\dist\bin\cross-env.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-09T18_22_08_016Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-09T18_22_08_158Z-debug.log
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034581/laravel-5-4-cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: After following this I find above problem

Answer (score 3):

Run these two lines, they were working for me.

```
   $ npm config rm proxy
   $ npm config rm https-proxy
```

Then, go for your command.

Answer (score 1):

please run : npm install then npm run watch

Comment: It would likely be more useful to the community if you explained what your solution does, and why you're proposing it. That will help especially new users who might stumble over this type of problem. E.g., something like "It sounds like you may not have the `watch` module installed. Before running `npm run watch`, try running `npm install` to make sure that all of your dependencies are installed and up-to-date."