# `npm run dev` results in Windows error `'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Tags: laravel, npm

> @ dev D:\xampp\htdocs\sports
>
> npm run development
>
> @ development D:\xampp\htdocs\sports
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> errno 1 npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-01T00_56_48_373Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @
> dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-01T00_56_48_496Z-debug.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 ‘cross-env’ Is Not Recognized as an Internal or External Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034581/laravel-5-4-cross-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 4):

You need install `cross-env` globally.

1. Remove `node_modules` folder
2. Run:

```sh
npm install --global cross-env
```

3. Remove `cross-env: ^x.y.z`, from your `package.json` project file.
4. Run

```sh
npm install --no-bin-links
```

5. Run and Test again:

```sh
npm run development
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and test again

```
npm run watch
```