# npm run watch command not working properly

Tags: npm, websocket, laravel-8, node-modules, nvm

I have laravel installed with version 8.83.27.

**Node version : 8.17.0** -

**npm version : 6.13.4**

When I'm going to execute `npm run watch`, it gives me an error like,

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '..'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/project/node_modules/.bin/cross-env:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I couldn't find the exact issue in this. What this error says?
Thanks.

**Update**

I don't want to update the node version to latest. Because websocket server is working great in this version. Just problem is when I click on any link, it keeps logout in this version.

So if I update the node version, websocket is not working properly and keeps sending error like, `"wss://chat.project.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"`.

Comment: The error message indicates that the cross-env module cannot be found or loaded. npm install cross-env

Comment: Thanks @KarlHill, but when I installed command `npm install cross-env`, it gives an error like,


`npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/project/node_modules/.bin/cross-env
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /var/www/html/project/node_modules/.bin/cross-env: is outside /var/www/html/project/node_modules/cross-env and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /var/www/html/project/node_modules/.bin/cross-env
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my issue with below answered link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467960

According to this issue comment, editing cross-env path will fix the problem. Change `cross-env` to `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js` in `package.json` like this:

```
"dev": "npm run development",
"development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
"hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```