# What is the correct way to Deploy a Laravel React App using Git?

Tags: reactjs, git, laravel

Thank you for reading this. Here is the Detailed Info

I am familiar with deploying multiple Laravel Apps. I am trying to deploy a Laravel React App for the first time. Here are the steps I followed

Used Git to push the ready app using following commands

- git add .
- git commit -m "initial production commit"
- git push origin master
  At the server
- git clone [git repo url]
- composer install
- setup env
- npm install
  Now here is the issues it gives me all kind of errors like "peer dependency does not meet" for babel-core, react, react-dom and many more. Then I started to install it manually as after searching on internet I realized it does not install dependencies automatically. Now when I install react 16 it gives me error

> requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

and when I install react 15 it gives me error for react 16. I have already tried this link : [How to deploy react laravel project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356861/how-to-deploy-react-laravel-project)

When I push all the code using git push --all -f it pushes everything including configuration and then it works on server.

How do I do it ? Is there any other way to deploy ? what are the right steps to be followed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in 99% of situations your local npm version is different from server npm version however you don't need and ideally you should not install npm into your server because npm and node_modules are for development only and all you need to do is to use compiled `js/css` file to your project. again it does not necessary to install npm into your server.
Best regards

Comment: how do we use that ? where is that file ? do we have to push it ?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, the output path usually is in `webpack.mix.js`